# Shared Object Files not creating - Boost, Python, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, shared-library, boost

System : Ubuntu 18.04.  Python 3.8 is my global install, but I have multiple local installs of various versions of Python from 2.7, 3.4, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9.

I have a project I am using with a boost dependency. When I try to import it it says

```
ImportError: libboost_python36.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

To confirm it doesn't exist I did

```
locate libboost_python36
```

and found no results. However, doing

```
locate libboost_python
```

did bring up a file called

```
libboost_python38.so.1.71.0
```

Presumably because I needed it for a different project on a different python installation.

To perform the boost install I downloaded the correct version from their release ( boost_1_67_0.tar.gz ) and extracted it. I then did the following commands

```
cd boost_1_67_0
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=/home/myusername/.local/bin/python3.6m --with-python-version=python3.6
sudo ./b2 install
sudo ./bjam install
```

However upon completing I get the same error and I still do not find a file called libboost_python36.so.1.67.0 when I run a locate.

What can I be doing wrong that I am not generating such a shared object file?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are probably inventing wheel.

All the mentioned software is [already packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libboost_python) in Ubuntu repositories. Start with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

Use commands below to get Python 3.6 binding for

- Boost 1.62:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.62-dev
  ```
- Boost 1.65:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.65-dev
  ```

Having Python 3.8 may create problems on system level.